# Offset Index Match with Row Drag

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, offset

Currently I have this formula which is working

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($K$5:$AP$5,MATCH(D7,$K$5:$AP$5,0)),2,-1,200,3)
```

My issue is I need to make the row reference IE: 2, dynamic so when I drag the formula down it gets update by automatically by 1 row. I can't seem to figure it out, currently having to manually change the row reference and I have to much data to do that, any ideas?

Comment: Change it to `Row(2:2)`  Then it will go to 3 then 4 when dragged down.

Comment: What is the **actual** purpose (i.e. functionality)? Surely you do not want to just put the first cell from a data block 200 rows x 3 columns into a cell?

Comment: There is no row reference `IE:2` in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($K$5:$AP$5,MATCH(D7,$K$5:$AP$5,0)),ROW(A2),-1,200,3)
```